# Как сделать так, чтобы изменения в Live Prewiew Brackets отображались автоматически без сохранения файла?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, brackets

Изменения в файле во время Live Preview вступают в силу только если сохранить файл. Как сделать так, чтобы изменения отображались автоматически?

Comment: про брекетс не знаю но это работает в vscode

Comment: @MaximLensky о я не знал что в VS Code тоже есть Live Preview. Сейчас попробую

Comment: @MaximLensky а каким расширением Вы пользуетесь в VS Code для Live Preview?

Comment: @MaximLensky я разобрался, как это сделать в Brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение**
Нужно открывать всю директорию, и тогда все будет работать. (Файл -> Открыть директорию)